# Yarn Launch Container Failed with Privilege Issue

Tags: hadoop-yarn, privileges

Stack: Ambari 2.4.2.0, HDP 2.5.3.0, CentOS 6.8, FreeIPA 3.0.0

When I try to use **hdp** user to submit a job on yarn, _000001 container can be created and launched successfully, but I got error when _000002 container is being launched after container created:

```
2018-11-27 22:13:35,919 WARN  privileged.PrivilegedOperationExecutor (PrivilegedOperationExecutor.java:executePrivilegedOperation(170)) - Shell execution returned exit code: 255. Privileged Execution Operation Output:
main : command provided 1
main : run as user is hdp
main : requested yarn user is hdp
Getting exit code file...
Creating script paths...
Writing pid file...
Writing to tmp file /hadoop/yarn/local/nmPrivate/application_1543327888220_0001/container_e14_1543327888220_0001_01_000002/container_e14_1543327888220_0001_01_000002.pid.tmp
Writing to cgroup task files...
Creating local dirs...
Launching container...
Getting exit code file...
Creating script paths...
Full command array for failed execution:
[/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-nodemanager/bin/container-executor, hdp, hdp, 1, application_1543327888220_0001, container_e14_1543327888220_0001_01_000002, /hadoop/yarn/local/usercache/hdp/appcache/application_1543327888220_0001/container_e14_1543327888220_0001_01_000002, /hadoop/yarn/local/nmPrivate/application_1543327888220_0001/container_e14_1543327888220_0001_01_000002/launch_container.sh, /hadoop/yarn/local/nmPrivate/application_1543327888220_0001/container_e14_1543327888220_0001_01_000002/container_e14_1543327888220_0001_01_000002.tokens, /hadoop/yarn/local/nmPrivate/application_1543327888220_0001/container_e14_1543327888220_0001_01_000002/container_e14_1543327888220_0001_01_000002.pid, /hadoop/yarn/local, /hadoop/yarn/log, cgroups=none]
2018-11-27 22:13:35,921 WARN  runtime.DefaultLinuxContainerRuntime (DefaultLinuxContainerRuntime.java:launchContainer(107)) - Launch container failed. Exception: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.linux.privileged.PrivilegedOperationException: ExitCodeException exitCode=255:
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.linux.privileged.PrivilegedOperationExecutor.executePrivilegedOperation(PrivilegedOperationExecutor.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.linux.runtime.DefaultLinuxContainerRuntime.launchContainer(DefaultLinuxContainerRuntime.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.linux.runtime.DelegatingLinuxContainerRuntime.launchContainer(DelegatingLinuxContainerRuntime.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.LinuxContainerExecutor.launchContainer(LinuxContainerExecutor.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:317)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:83)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: ExitCodeException exitCode=255:
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:933)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:844)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:1123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.linux.privileged.PrivilegedOperationExecutor.executePrivilegedOperation(PrivilegedOperationExecutor.java:150)
    ... 9 more
```

There is no more log about **Privilege**, anybody has some idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Problem resolved and the problem is submitted job itself not YARN/Privilege.

Suggestion is that you'd better try to find details in **container** log not resourcemanager/nodemanager log.

Comment: Hi Alan, could you say what was the problem with submitted job?

Comment: @sravani.s sorry to see comment just now, seems 4 years ago, i think, thats the job you submitted itself